# Shell parse string

Tags: shell, ksh

I read a string from a file with shell script variables, and want to substitute the variables with values in a function like

```
hello.txt:
-------------
Hello $NAME


a.sh 
-------------
function printout
{
  echo ???somehow_parse??? $1
}

NAME=Joe
printout "$(cat hello.txt)"
NAME=Nelly
printout "$(cat hello.txt)"
```

The example is not the best, but it describes my problem. In other words: can I use shell as a template engine?

I am using ksh.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lazy Evaluation in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900707/lazy-evaluation-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I would go for a search-and-replace approach using sed/awk such as that shown in [Kent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9129859/115845) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/407311/115845).

If you want a shell-only approach, then the standard way would be to use `eval`. However, this poses a security risk. For example:

```
[me@home]$ cat hello.txt
hello $NAME; uname -a
[me@home]$ NAME="shawn"
[me@home]$ eval echo "`cat hello.txt`"   # DO NOT DO THIS!
hello shawn
Linux SOMEHOST 2.6.9-101.ELsmp #1 SMP Fri May 27 18:57:30 EDT 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Notice how a command can be injected into the template!

You can however reduce the risk using this approach:

```
[me@home]$ eval "OUT=\"`cat hello.txt`\""
[me@home]$ echo $OUT
hello shawn; uname -a
```

Do note that **this is still not foolproof** as commands can still be injected using `$(cmd)` or `` `cmd` ``.

In short, you should use `eval` only if you understand the risks and can control/limit access to the template files.

Here's an example of how this can be applied in your script:

```
function printout {
    FILENAME=$1
    eval "OUT=\"`cat $FILENAME`\""
    echo $OUT
}

NAME=Joe
printout hello.txt
NAME=Nelly
printout hello.txt
```

Comment: This `eval` was what I wanted. It is sure risky, but the only user of my script is me. If I am a fool, shame on me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that the contents of your template file is completely safe, that is, it doesn't contain a string to execute a command that might harm your computer, then you can use [eval](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html#EVALREF):

```
#!/bin/bash
NAME=Joe
TEMPLATE=$(cat hello.txt)
eval "echo $TEMPLATE"
NAME=Nelly
eval "echo $TEMPLATE"
```

Example output:

```
HELLO Joe
HELLO Nelly
```

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
kent$  head hello.txt t.sh
==> hello.txt <==
hello $name

==> t.sh <==
#!/bin/bash

function printout
{
  echo $1|awk -v name="$name" 'gsub(/\$name/,name)'
}
name=xxx
printout "$(cat hello.txt)"
name=yyy
printout "$(cat hello.txt)"
```

run it:

```
kent$  ./t.sh
hello xxx
hello yyy
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is to use the `basename` utility.

For instance, if you have the following string: `a='/home/you/stuff/myfile.txt'` you could use commands like:

```
dirname $a
basename $a
basename $a .txt
```

and get output that looks like this:

```
/home/you/stuff
myfile.txt
myfile
```